# Creating a Chatbox with AJAX, HTML and C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, chatroom

I am using the Nancy Web Framework in my C# Console Application to basically create a Web Administration panel for my software. I have opted to use the Spark View Engine, as it is basically just HTML. I basically want to create a chatbox, except pull the data written to my application's console every X seconds and display it in a box instead.

I have very little experience with JQuery and AJAX, but they aren't overly complicated from the examples I have seen. The issue I am running into is that ALL of the chatbox and shoutbox examples use PHP.

I basically just need something like this...

[image]

The only difference is I need to pull the information from my application instead. I can use basic C# methods inside of the HTML (and probably inside of javascript but I haven't tried this). What would be the best way to do this, and are there any examples floating around that don't use PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to use HTML for styling inside some PC program is just not wise. It has much better UI engines, though. But for your information [here is nice jQuery shoutbox tutorial](http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/create-a-shoutbox-using-php-and-ajax-jquery/), but well, you only need to handle data input and output with C#, so actually I see no problems. The engine which you are using should have some kind of data stream, or requests handler (`bla://program/???`)

Comment: I never said I am using HTML for styling my application. I am using HTML for creating a Web Administration Panel (as I said in my question). Also, that JQuery Shoutbox tutorial is based around PHP, which is specifically what I was asking to avoid. I was having trouble location chat/shoutbox scripts that are simply HTML based.

Comment: you cant have ONLY html based. You still nedd some kinde of server. With ajax you can make request to any web page and prase that data. At this point you can use Ruby, Python, ASP and so on. But at this case you using C# what makes no diffrence at frontend. But why you dont want to use PHP witch is much better then some kide of C engine.

Answer (score 0):

This was completed using AJAX and JSON.